# Acrescentar assinatura no email do Outlook

Tags: vba

Criei este código para enviar emails depois de seleccionar concluído no Excel, infelizmente não consigo adicionar a assinatura do Outlook no código. Podem ajudar-me?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oMail As Object
    Dim text As String
    Dim Sigsting As String


    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)

            linha = ActiveCell.Row
            text = "Presado " & Sheet1.Cells(linha, 2) & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                   " " & Sheet1.Cells(linha, 7) & " aberta em " & _
                   ""

            If Target.Address = "$F$" & linha Then

                If Sheet1.Cells(linha) = "Concluido" Then
                End If



                With oMail

                .To = Sheet1.Cells(linha, 1).text
                .Subject = ""
                .Body = text
                .Display

                End With

                On Error GoTo 0

                Set oMail = Nothing
                Set oApp = Nothing

            End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Qual é exatamente a sua dúvida? Poderia acrescentar mais detalhes?

Comment: Queria acrescentar a assinatura do outlook no código. Experimentei (.HTMLBody) mas não funciona. Talvez seja por causa do late binding.